# How to avoid multiple conditions in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

please let me know how do I avoid the multiple conditions in C#.

This is my code :-

```
 private static bool CheckForConverted(string policynumber)
    {
        string[] prefix = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };

        if (policynumber.StartsWith("0") || policynumber.StartsWith("1") || policynumber.StartsWith("2") || policynumber.StartsWith("3") || policynumber.StartsWith("4"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Use a array then do array.Any(a => a == true)

Comment: You could use a regex.  `^[0-4]` would do it.

Comment: can you please suggest me in my case how I apply this using array ?

Comment: The linked duplicate shows how to use an array of strings with StartsWith...

Comment: @HereticMonkey But it should be easy to deduce the answer from it.

Comment: @ikwillem `return "01234".Any(o => policyNumber.First() == o);` ? Works but I wouldn't say it's more readable

Comment: @Marshal Indeed, that's what I'm saying. The duplicate is easy to follow and apply to this question.

Comment: @mackie haha, I didn't have enought time to write the full answer yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static bool CheckForConverted(string policynumber)
{
    string[] prefix = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    return policynumber != null && prefix.Any(e => policynumber.StartsWith(e));        
}
```

Or you can use Method Group syntax

```
    private static bool CheckForConverted(string policynumber)
    {
        string[] prefix = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        return policynumber != null && prefix.Any(policynumber.StartsWith);
    }
```

Comment: Can someone explain the negative vote, please?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It worked perfect

Answer (score -1):

For you prefix array it should be as simple as:

```
private static bool CheckForConverted(string policynumber)
{
    string[] prefix = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    return prefix.Any(pr => policynumber.StartsWith(pr))
}
```

This uses LINQ's [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) method which already returns boolean, so you don't need if-else.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It worked perfect